# PC stopped connecting to Internet or router over WiFi

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

My Windows (10 1909) PC connects to the router via WiFi. Other PCs as well.

Suddenly I lost Internet.
I can see WiFi networks and connect to them, but cannot ping any site including the router IP.
All other PCs, tablets and phones can access Internet via WiFi just fine. And they can access the router IP.

- I troubleshooted. "No valid IP configuration". (I just use default DHCP)
- I reset WiFi adapter.
- I re-plugged WiFi adapter. In a different USB slot.
- I hibernated and woke the PC.
- I installed a different WiFi adapter.
- I restarted the router.

What could be the issue and how to fix it?

P.S. I'm pretty sure the issue would go away after restart.

Update:

I've tried to set up IP configuration manually and it worked.
Switched back to DHCP and it stopped working.

I've looked in the Event viewer and I see an error:

```
WLAN Extensibility Module has failed to start.

Module Path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\Rtlihvs.dll
Error Code: 126
```

This `Rtlihvs.dll` file does not exist anywhere on my PC.

Update 2:

This issue has been present for ~24 hours. Then I switched to manual IP configuration. This worked. I changed back to DHCP - everything broke again. I restarted the "WLAN AutoConfig" service. At first it looked like the issue is not fixed, but after couple of hours I've noticed that DHCP now works.

So, perhaps restarting "WLAN AutoConfig" has a positive effect on this issue.

Comment: setup the ip config manually and see if it works. how did you troubleshoot? what happens if you use the USB-WiFi adapter on a different device?

Comment: Thank you. The WiFi adapters work fine on other devices. Thank you for the suggestion to set IP manually. As obvious as it sounds, sometimes it takes another person to tell you what to do =) The Internet worked with manual config. And it looks like I managed to fix DHCP by restarting the "WLAN AutoConfig" service.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the "WLAN AutoConfig" service to fix DHCP. It seems to have helped me, although not immediately. Saw the suggestion at [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/wlan-extensibility-module-has-failed-to-start/164632cb-a4f1-4364-a2be-b617ef75306a)

For an immediate solution, as @Albin said, set the adapter's IP configuration manually.

E.g.:

```
IP: 192.168.0.123
Net Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.1
DNS: 8.8.8.8
DNS: 1.1.1.1
```